# Object Manipulation (grouping)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a nested object like this.

```
data = {
    2000: {
        1: {
            a: {year: 2000, no: 1, alphabet: 'a'}
        }, 
        2: {
            a: {year: 2000, no: 2, alphabet: 'a'}
        },
        3: {
            a: {year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'a'},
            b: {year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'b'}
        }
    },
    2010: {
        1: {
            a: {year: 2010, no: 1, alphabet: 'a'}
        }, 
        2: {
            a: {year: 2010, no: 2, alphabet: 'a'}
        },
        3: {
            a: {year: 2010, no: 3, alphabet: 'a'},
            b: {year: 2010, no: 3, alphabet: 'b'}
        }
    }
}

requestedType = {
    years: [
    {
        year: "2000",
        nos: [
            {
                no: 1,
                alphs: [
                    {
                        alph: "a",
                        data: {year: 2000, no: 1, alphabet: 'a'}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                no: 2,
                alphs: [
                    {
                        alph: "a",
                        data: {year: 2000, no: 2, alphabet: 'a'}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                no: 3,
                alphs: [
                    {
                        alph: "a",
                        data: {year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'a'}
                    },
                    {
                        alph: "b",
                        data: {year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'b'}
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
       year: "2010",
       nos: [........]
    }
    ]

}
```

I want to change this data to that structure.

Basically I can do that with this function but I want to do that dynamically

I tried using recursion (call same function inside foreach loop, but it doesn't work the way I expect. Because, I guess because of async behaviour of Javascript).

```
var years =  Object.keys(data)
years.forEach((year, i) => {
    var noData = result[year]
    years[i] = {year, no: noData}

    var nos =  Object.keys(noData)
    nos.forEach((no, j) => {
        var alpData = noData[no]
        nos[j] = {no, alphabet: alpData}
    });
    years[i]["nos"] = nos

    ....................

});
```

Waiting your help, any suggestion would be perfect

**edit:** 
solution should be dynamic. It might be more complex data structure than this. For example: 
Thank you so much for your answer but actually I don't want to get hard coded solution. Maybe I should add this to the question as well but assume that it might be more nested objects like 5 - 6 more steps go to inside.

a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { data: data } } } } } so on.

Basically you can think like we have an array that contains all this

fields. ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

Comment: is years in requestedType  array type? currently yeaar 2000 is available and adding 2010 will be part of years array right

Comment: @NagaSaiA Yes it should be array for sure. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: please share that possible 5-6 nested object in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = {
  2000: {
    1: { a: { year: 2000, no: 1, alphabet: 'a' } },
    2: { a: { year: 2000, no: 2, alphabet: 'a' } },
    3: { a: { year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'a' },
         b: { year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'b' } }
  },
  2010: {
    1: { a: { year: 2010, no: 1, alphabet: 'a' } },
    2: { a: { year: 2010, no: 2, alphabet: 'a' } },
    3: { a: { year: 2010, no: 3, alphabet: 'a' },
         b: { year: 2010, no: 3, alphabet: 'b' } }
  }
}

var keys = ["year", "no", "alphabet"]

  function magic(data, i, keys){
      var label = keys[i] + 's'
      var next = keys[i+1] + 's'
      return Object.entries(data).map(el => {
        var res = {}
        res[label] = el[0]
        if(i !== keys.length-1){
            res[next] =  magic(el[1], i+1, keys)
        } else {
            var key = Object.keys(data)
            res["data"] = data[key[0]]
        }
        return res
      })
  }

r = magic(data, 0, keys)
console.log(r)
```

I found a solution by changing little bit @GalAbra solution.

Thank you very much for your help. You did the most of job ! **Object.entries** was the good call !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `requestedType.years` is an array, this is the (very complicated) structure you've described:

```js
// Exactly the same as yours, but in a more compact format
const data = {
  2000: {
    1: { a: { year: 2000, no: 1, alphabet: 'a' } },
    2: { a: { year: 2000, no: 2, alphabet: 'a' } },
    3: { a: { year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'a' },
         b: { year: 2000, no: 3, alphabet: 'b' } }
  },
  2010: {
    1: { a: { year: 2010, no: 1, alphabet: 'a' } },
    2: { a: { year: 2010, no: 2, alphabet: 'a' } },
    3: { a: { year: 2010, no: 3, alphabet: 'a' },
         b: { year: 2010, no: 3, alphabet: 'b' } }
  }
}

const requestedType = {
  years: Object.entries(data).map(year => {
    return {
      year: year[0],
      nos: Object.entries(year[1]).map(yearContent => {
        return {
          no: yearContent[0],
          alphs: Object.entries(yearContent[1]).map(itemContent => {
            return {
              alph: itemContent[0],
              data: itemContent[1]
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
console.log(requestedType);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but actually I don't want to get hard coded solution. Maybe I should add this to the question as well but assume that it might be more nested objects like 5 - 6 more steps go to inside. 
a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { data: data } } } } } etc.

Comment: I couldn't understand the logic of your expected result, but I hope you can use this to create your own solution :)